# Print ping response time while higher than a fixed value, including date

Tags: sed, awk

I like to have a running ping that only prints output while passing a threshold value.
And if passing this value, also add date to the output.

Here is what I have tried:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | awk '{split($7,a,"[=.]");if (a[2]>58) print a[2],d}' d="$(date)"
ping 8.8.8.8 | awk '{"date"| getline date;split($7,a,"[=.]");if (a[2]>58) print a[2],date}'
```

Problem with both of these is that `date` is not updated. All is printed with same date.

```
59 Fri Nov 15 08:55:04 CET 2013
59 Fri Nov 15 08:55:04 CET 2013
59 Fri Nov 15 08:55:04 CET 2013
60 Fri Nov 15 08:55:04 CET 2013
59 Fri Nov 15 08:55:04 CET 2013
```

I know this could be solved using a bash script, but I just like to have a simple command line when testing line ping time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | awk '{split($7,a,"[=.]");if (a[2]>58) print a[2],d}' d="$(date)"
```

the variable `d` is evaluated only once due to which you get the same timestamp appended to all the lines in the output.  You could instead use [`strftime`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) as an argument to `print`:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | awk '{split($7,a,"[=.]");if (a[2]>58) print a[2], strftime()}'
```

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me.  I'm using OSX Mavericks:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | awk -F"[= ]" '{if($10>50) {cmd="date"; cmd | getline dt; close(cmd) ; print $10, dt}}'
```

This will output the ping line for times > 50 ms.

I get this sample output:

```
51.352 Fri Nov 15 00:33:40 PST 2013
50.519 Fri Nov 15 00:33:42 PST 2013
52.407 Fri Nov 15 00:33:44 PST 2013
50.904 Fri Nov 15 00:33:50 PST 2013
52.864 Fri Nov 15 00:33:54 PST 2013
```

Comment: Does not answer my question.  I would like to time stamp it. Adding date. You solution could be written `awk -F"[= ]" '$10>50'`

Comment: You're right. I was focused on the comparison in awk, and forgot about the date part. :)  I updated with a way to append the date.

Comment: Your solution worked, but accepted solution from devnul since it used only internal function, but credits for your work :)

Comment: Thanks.  However, strftime() isn't available in the default shell on OSX.  I tried both Mavericks and Mountain Lion.